# Error In phyloseq alpha-diversity plot - getting a dimensions warning

Tags: r, phyloseq

[using plot_richness and sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64n9n.png)

myData is a phyloseq data set with 5 taxa from six samples

I tried removing and adding variable and nothing gets rid of the error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a dependency issue, where `vegan::fisher.alpha` no longer accepts (and outputs) the SE option - for more info, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq/issues/1581). Unfortunately, it seems that phyloseq is no longer being maintained, so this issue is unlikely to get resolved. I suggest to omit the calculation of `fisher.alpha`:

```
plot_richness(myData, x="BODY_SITE", color="Description", measures = c("Observed", "Chao1", "ACE", "Shannon", "Simpson", "InvSimpson"))
```

If you absolutely need `fisher.alpha`, you can calculate it directly through `vegan` and plot it independently.